# Como desativar o Auto-Preenchimento dos Navegadores?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Essa tela é de cadastro do meu sistema.

E aqui o input.

`<input id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password" autocomplete="off" value="">`

como podem ver já usei o autocomplete mais não funcionou

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: Quer saber a programação ou somente para uso pessoal?

Comment: Quero saber na programação

Answer (score -1):

marca o atributo autocomplete do input como `off` :

`<input autocomplete="on|off">`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: já tentei não funcionou

Comment: Tenta no `form`.

Comment: não uso form uso json

Comment: Toda documentação oficial e os próprios comentários dos desenvolvedores recomendam que não se faça isso.

Comment: @Renan não vi isso na documentação, e me pergunto porque teria uma opção que não é recomendada utilizar, se possível, coloque o link para que eu possa ver isso. Realmente não sabia, obrigado; vlw

Comment: Já ouvi que deixar habilitado é inseguro, agora desabilitar? Bah...

Comment: Segue um link em português da MDN que fala sobre isso: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion - note que ao final do texto a MDN relata que isso não funciona nos principais browsers.

Comment: Segue a explicação do time do Chrome explicando porque desativar a autocompleção é inseguro: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2013OctDec/1002.html

Comment: E por fim: abriram um bug pro Chromium por cauaa desse comportamento e o time marcou como *won't fix*: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153

Comment: @Renan 'Toda documentação oficial e os próprios comentários dos desenvolvedores recomendam que não se faça isso. ' não entendi. Isso que você falou seria que não posso usar o json para enviar formulários

Comment: @George não, eu estava falando sobre essa resposta.

Comment: @Renan obrigado pelas referências, não se trata da documentação do html, mas é válido apesar de discordar da justificativa dada

Comment: Eu também não concordo com a justificativa dada, pra mim isso sim é inseguro, dado que por salvar as senhas automaticamente alguém não autorizado pode acessar seus dados. Fora que qualquer um pode ir lá no gerenciar senhas salvas e ver sua senha. Esse motivo de os usuários poderem escolher senhas mais fortes devido ao browser poder salvar sua senha também não me convence, pra mim isso isso gera mais problemas que resolve. Mas enfim, também não sabia que eles ignoravam o `autocomplete=off` por padrão nos campos de login, bom saber!